# Comparing Gini indices and Hill numbers between groups

Tags: r, statistics, glm, gini

Also [posted on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568050/comparing-gini-indices-and-hill-numbers-between-groups) but I think I might get more traction here.

I'm looking a `R` packages that can test for differences in `Gini` indices and `Hill` numbers between two groups. The `R` `package` `simboot`'s `sbdiv` function does that for the `Shannon` and `Simpson` diversity indices:

```
library(simboot)
data(predatGM)
#filter the predatGM data.frame to keep only two Variety groups and refactor:
predatGM <- dplyr::filter(predatGM,Variety %in% c("GM","S1"))
predatGM$Variety <- factor(predatGM$Variety, levels = c("GM","S1"))
simboot::sbdiv(X = dplyr::select(predatGM,-Block,-Variety),f = predatGM$Variety, theta = "Shannon", alternative = "two.sided")
simboot::sbdiv(X = dplyr::select(predatGM,-Block,-Variety),f = predatGM$Variety, theta = "Simpson", alternative = "two.sided")
```

So I'm looking for something equivalent for `Gini` indices and `Hill` numbers.

Comment: `help(package="simboot")` does say "Further simboot allows for comparing biological diversities of two or more groups while simultaneously testing a user-defined selection of Hill numbers of orders q" ...  which seems to answer one of your questions?  (FWIW "Looking for a package" is technically off-topic for SO, while the same question rephrased as "how can I ... ?" is on-topic ...)

Comment: (See `?mcpHill` ...)